# How to prove the graph is a tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

A graph H=(V,E) has 10 vertices and 12 edges.is it a tree? Give a reason. Justify your reason by staying a related theorem.

Answer (score 4):

No, if a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) has $v$ vertices, then it has $v-1$ edges. $12 \neq 10-1$, so it is not a tree.